# OPENROWSET load XML with different type

Tags: sql-server, xml

I was trying to load XML via `OPENROWSET`, when check the loaded data it was in different characters. I use below code for that,

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\GET_QUOTA_DATA_resTEST.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x) Y
```

Results I am getting for above query was as below

```
0x3C534F41502D454E563A456E76656C6F70652078......
```

What could be the reason. How can I load the XML as it is?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:toa:capacity">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:get_quota_data_response>
        <bucket>
        <bucket_id>FT_10503_DP1019</bucket_id>
        <name>ABC Co</name>
            <day>
                <date>2015-08-21</date>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast BulkColumn to XML.

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = CAST(BulkColumn AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\GET_QUOTA_DATA_resTEST.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x
```

Comment: That's look good. My next issue was parsing the XML. It doesn't show any values. I will raise new question for that

Comment: XML file is good, results empty though. `DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\GET_QUOTA_DATA_resTEST.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x


SELECT 
BucketBucket_id = bucket.value('(bucket_id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
BucketName = bucket.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
FROM
@XmlFile.nodes('/bucket') AS XTbl1(bucket) `

Comment: Start new question + provide sample xml for test.